# Why did one of my effects stopped working after adding another effect?

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototypejs, scriptaculous

I am new to all of this so sorry if this is a stupid question.

I had previously created a lightbox affect for my contact form and had it working great. Clicked contact, lightbox popped up with the contact form that kept in a separate html page. The script references were as follows:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/lightview.css" />
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/prototype/1.6.1/prototype.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/scriptaculous/1.8.2/scriptaculous.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/lightview.js'></script>
```

Then, I went through a tutorial to add a coda-like slider box and got that all working adding the following scripts to the head:

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.scrollTo-1.4.2-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.localscroll-1.2.7-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.serialScroll-1.2.2-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/coda-slider.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Once I completed that I found that my initial lightbox function stopped working and the link now just sent me to the html page. No lightbox. Here is the full head now:

```
<title>index</title> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" media="screen" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/lightview.css" />
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/prototype/1.6.1/prototype.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/scriptaculous/1.8.2/scriptaculous.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/lightview.js'></script>
<script src="js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.scrollTo-1.4.2-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.localscroll-1.2.7-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.serialScroll-1.2.2-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/coda-slider.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Here is my nav that sent to the light box:

```
    <a href="index.html">Overview</a> |
    <a href="index.html">Client List</a> |
    <a href="index.html">Reviews</a> |
    <a href="index.html">News</a> |
    <a href='hiddenforms/candidateform.html' class='lightview' title=" :: :: topclose: true, autosize: true">Candidates</a> | 
    <a href='hiddenforms/contactform.html' class='lightview' title=" :: :: topclose: true, autosize: true">Contact</a> | 
    <a href="candidate.html">Share</a>
```

I hope that helps. Can you have too much javascript on a page? How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look in your error console (Firebug, Web Inspector, etc) for errors. If one script is overwriting properties the other script is expecting, it may break something. You also might want to consider at least deploying with all of your scripts concatenated to a single file, to reduce network lag.

Edit: It might also be a conflict between jQuery and Prototype and/or Scriptaculous. jQuery tries to avoid conflicts with other libraries, but only so much of this can be controlled. Ensure jQuery is loaded before the other scripts and add `jQuery.noConflict();` to the end.

Comment: Thanks man...question...when you say to add jQuery.noConflict... to the end, do you mean to the end of the script in the head? Or is that somewhere in the .js file?

Comment: To the end of your jQuery .js file.

Comment: Not real familiar with javascript so not really sure where in the file to put it. The entire thing, for example, ends: ..."px")}})})();

Comment: Immediately after that. At the very end.

Comment: Thanks again. That didn't work but probably bc I don't understand enough. I appreciate all your time.

Comment: Can you please look in the error console (Firebug or Web Inspector) and share any errors that appear when you load the page?

Comment: Yea...I will do today. Thanks.

Comment: This is what it says when the code from above is run. Error: element.dispatchEvent is not a function
Source File: http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/prototype/1.6.1/prototype.js
Line: 4619

Comment: This is one of the first results I got when I googled that error: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/415550/prototype-and-jquery-peaceful-co-existence

Answer (score 3):

I had kind of the same issue. I have both the Wordpress plugins "Lightbox 2" and "PressOK - Collapsible Region" installed. After installing PressOK - Collapsible Region, the Lightbox effect stopped working.

After checking the code, I found the solution by commenting out one line of code in pressok-collapsible-region/PressOK-collapsible-region.php, as shown below. Now both plugins work! I hope this helps.

```
function collapsible_region_javascript() {

/*   echo '<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>'; */

    $siteroot = get_bloginfo('wpurl');
    echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="' . $siteroot . '/wp-content/plugins/pressok-collapsible-region/style.css" />';
    echo '<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="' . $siteroot . '/wp-content/plugins/pressok-collapsible-region/collapsible-region.js"></script>';
}
```